# How To Drag Two Divs Simultaneously - JQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 3 divs and I am using JQuery Sortable Plugin. It is working fine, but the problem is that I have placed an another small div (in black color) on the lower right corner of the 1st Div what I want is that when I drag the first div anywhere the small div drags with it too. 
Here's the code,

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="eng">
        <head>
    <title>Drag 2 divs same time</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        </head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="div1" > Div 1</div>
<div id= "small"></div>
<div id="div2" > Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" > Div 3</div>
</div>
<script>
$('#wrapper').sortable({ cancel: "#small"});
$('#wrapper').disableSelection();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#div2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#div1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
     margin-left: 5px;
}
#div3{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
     margin-left: 5px;
}
#small{
    width:25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 88px;
    top: 83px;
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: [disableSelection()](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/) is deprecated in v 1.9 and you shoulnd't use it anyway as the docs state.

Comment: may be css positioning can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the small div inside the actual div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1" > Div 1
    <div id= "small"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" > Div 2</div>
  <div id="div3" > Div 3</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vrc9Y/

Comment: Can you explain what you want small div to do? Do you want it to stay at the bottom right of div1 all the time?

Comment: Yes I want it to stick with the div1

Comment: And why don't you want to put it inside the div?

Comment: Actually I want to apply a background-image and want to place it at the edge of the lower right corner of the div. If I make it inner div it will remain inside the Div1 and can't be place on the edge of the Div1. That's why I want it to be the outer div.